# Form shrink during start up

Tags: windows, delphi

Some weeks ago a user reported that the GUI of my program was shrink. 
Today I started my laptop in multi-monitor mode and could reproduce the problem: at windows start up, the size of the main form was 325x243 pixels instead of 648x700.

I have no single line of code that controls the width/height of the form. The position is set like this: `MainForm.Position:= poDefault`. The user cannot resize the form ( `BorderStyle:= bsSingle` ).

What could cause such weirdness?
It is the second time when I start my laptop with additional monitors attached. The first time everything was ok. Could it be related to this multi-monitor configuration?

If the compiler generates no code related to form's size then it is like some external program injected code into my program to change its size. It is plausible. There are programs that are doing so in order to control how windows are spread over multiple monitors. I have one of them installed but it is not running at Windows start up.

Comment: ...and that program is called Windows.  When you opened the list of `MainForm.Position` values you saw three different default values: default size, default position and default size and position. I can only wonder that seeing that you did not got curious what the diference there is between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The position is set like this: MainForm.Position:= poDefault

And that is the answer.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.Position

*The form appears in a position on the screen and with a **height and width determined by the operating system**.*

However there are other options like

***poDefaultPosOnly**: The form displays with the size you created it at design time, but the operating system chooses its position on the screen*

***poScreenCenter**: The form remains the size you left it at design time, but is positioned in the center of the screen.*

And many others.

Additionally, you may avoid fixing the issue and add a workaround instead: just set the form size fixed using http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.Constraints

Comment: The program worked for years!!! Like this. I don't understand why the OS decided to change my form's width/height.

Comment: Why do you write the code, when you just can set it in DFM via Objects Inspector instead ?

Comment: Who knows why... But the fact is that your program did not ensured the required conditions and instead gambled that someone else would do it. It is fragile. It is typical that this works for years  then some butterfly flaps the wings and it works no more - and usually  you can hardly tell what was the trigger :-)

Comment: I just wanted to log the size while the program starts :)

Comment: To log it you just make your own overrode methods `TMainForm.AfterConstruction` and `TMainForm.Loaded` and add event `TMainForm.OnShow` - those hooks would tell you all the story.